# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CIS100 ' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Can somebody help me? I'm trying to run a count command so it counts all of the students that are in each class number so I'm running this command. Although I'm getting this error.

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'CIS100              ' to data type int

Here's my SQL Query

```
USE RMUDB
GO
SELECt *
FROM Class
WHERE [Class Number] = (Select Count([Class Number]) FROM Enrollment)
```

Comment: `COUNT` should be in the `SELECT` list as a calculated field. Use `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Kindly show to us your tables with sample values so we can see it clearly what's wrong in your query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count the students in each class, doesn't the following query do what you want?

```
SELECT c.[Class Number], COUNT(e.[Class Number])
FROM Class c LEFT JOIN
     Enrollment e
     ON c.[Class Number] = e.[Class Number]
GROUP BY c.[Class Number];
```

Your query is comparing the result of a counting operation (an integer) to `[Class Number]`, which is the name of something.  It is unlikely that `=` makes sense.